# Instantiating struct with string that has string.reserve()

Tags: c++, string, memory-management

I want to pass a string with `string.reserve(1000)` and ensure that memory is allocated when I pass it into different structs.  Is there a way to do this without explicitly doing it after every instantiation?

I want to avoid having to do this:

```
struct Prefix{
  std::string path;
};

int main() {
  std::string path = "hel";
  path.reserve(1000);
  std::cout << path.capacity() << "\n"; // 1000

  Prefix x = {path};
  std::cout << x.path.capacity() << "\n"; // 15
  x.path.reserve(1000);
  x.path += somestring;
  Prefix y = {x.path};
  std::cout << y.path.capacity() << "\n"; // 15
  y.reserve(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it explicitly, compiler is not required to copy the capacity too when copying `std::string`.

You can add a constructor to do it for you.

```
struct Prefix{
  std::string path;
  Prefix(const string& p) : path(p) { path.reserve(p.capacity()); }
};
```

Comment: What if the capacity is a variable?  Would I have to use a class instead?

Comment: @user18764 What do you mean about *capacity is a variable* ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the origin string again, you should move rather than copy.

```
Prefix x = {std::move(path)};
```

This isn't technically guaranteed to preserve the capacity, but it's hard to imagine a sane implementation where it wouldn't work. (And no, SSO doesn't affect this, it just enforces a minimum capacity at all times).